# Django /Python Program Flow and Structure

Tags: python, django, import

I am a new developer and have been learning Python and Django.  I'm trying to understand the structure and flow behind the scenes and I'm confused by a line of code that I encountered.  Well, I'm actually confused by a number of things but this is one specific example.  Can someone help me understand the flow of the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

When I search the library files in my virtual environment I find a folder called django and inside that folder I find contrib and inside that folder I find admin.  I see that that the **init**.py file in the admin package has import statements that import in * which I understand to be everything in the various modules that are available.  When I go digging through the various modules, I find sites.py and inside sites.py I find a "site" variable that is an object that has been instantiated.  Here is the snippet of code from the sites.py module:

```
site = DefaultAdminSite()
```

Ok, here is where I'm confused.  Looking back at the original code, where does the "register" function get pulled in.  I'm accessing a variable that contains an instantiated object from the class DefaultAdminSite().  That class is also defined in sites.py and is a child class of LazyObject.  LazyObject is defined in the module located at django.utils.functional.  There is no register method or attribute there either.

So in summary here is what I think the code is doing.  It's accessing the instantiated object "site" which is located at django.contrib.admin.sites.site.  But then that site object is accessing a "register something or another" and passing in the Post model that I created.  I just can't find "register" anywhere.  Can somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: There is a register [function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c1c361677d9400c8e2cdaddda0c16086bb358492/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L86)

Comment: Where is the register function located?  Wouldn't it have to be in sites.py or functional.py in order for me to access it through the site object?

Comment: That is on the AdminSite class, I think you're confusion comes over lazy objects

Comment: Yes, this all makes sense now.  Thanks Sayse and Bruno.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted indeed - but that's often the case for complex frameworks. If you read the `DefaultAdminSite` code, you see this:

```
def _setup(self):
     AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
     self._wrapped = AdminSiteClass()
```

This loads the `AppConfig` object for the `admin` app, which (unless overriden) is in [`admin/apps.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c1c361677d9400c8e2cdaddda0c16086bb358492/django/contrib/admin/apps.py), and defines `default_site` as `'django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite'`.  This is then passed to `import_string()`, which will import the 'django.contrib.admin.sites' module and return the `AdminSite` class. `LazyObject` is a (kind of) [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), so technically, you want to look for the `register` method in  the `ÀdminSite` class.

Comment: Thank you Bruno!  Makes sense now.